# How to iterate over list of values of one key in a dictionary

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, key-value

i want to compare the values (a tuple of floats and a boolean variable) of matching keys of 2 different dictionaries to print out possible differences. The keys are IDs and I want to make sure to have the same values (that stand for certain monetary amounts) in both dictionaries.

```
 dict1 = {'4000' : (100.05, 200.08, 300.96, True), '1234': (39.45,1200.09,208.34, True)}
 dict2 = {'4000' : (100.05, 200.08, 400.96, True), '1234': (39.45,1205.09,208.34, True)}
```

What I want is to compare the values at the same indexes (100.05 == 100.05? 200.08 ==200.08? 300.96 == 400.96? and so on). Then I want to print out the differences if existing:

```
'Difference: Third Number, +100'
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you try a simple comparison: like `dict1['4000'] == dict2['4000']`?

Comment: Do you mean all values, one specific value, values of common keys only? In all cases, the answer is probably going to be a basic "just do it".

Comment: What did you try? And do you want to to know the differences in the tuples or just compare them for equality? Also tuples are not lists.

Comment: @KennyOstrom I want to compare the values of common keys, that stand at the same index

Comment: Doing two simple things in a row doesn't make them special. Just do it. You know how to iterate dictionaries. You know how to iterate tuples. Use == normally. If you post some code, and if there's a problem in that code, then everyone will be happy to point it out.

Comment: There is a chance that you are having a problem with comparing float values, in which case a [mcve] really would have helped. But it's pretty weird to get a problem if all the floats have two digits. If working with money, I prefer to use integer pennies, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You have not specified exactly what output you need but, assuming the length of our values are the same you can run something like this:

```
for k in dict1.keys():
   for i in range(len(dict1[k])):
       if dict1[k][i] != dict2[k][i]:
          print(k, i, dict1[k][i], dict2[k][i])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for key in list(dict1):
    val1 = dict1[key]
    val2 = dict2[key]
    for i in range(len(val1)):
        print(val1[i] == val2[i])
```